# No inner edge ring

Tags: edges

Does anybody see why my edge ring is only on the outside of the object, but not on the inside when I use the "Loop Cut and Slide"?

[image]

The red arrow points to where I expected the "inner" edge ring to appear.

Thank you.

Comment: the mouse cursor was at the red arrow ?

Comment: Are you trying to display the line that is on the outside, or are you trying to add it to the inside?

Comment: On the inside. For some "Loop Cut and Slide" it worked fine, then it stopped. I must have done something that made it stop worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inner ring never appears when you do this. You can alternatively use a solidify modifier, or you can follows these easy steps.

Add the edge loop on the outside.

Enable vertex snapping <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. [image]

Add the loop on the inside, then <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> and mouse over the outer loop.

[image]

Adding screenshots...

Comment: `An inner ring never appears when you do this.` I don't quite follow that . . .

Comment: You never get two rings (outer and inner) when you loop cut. I think he was confused with the functions of the loop cut.

Comment: You might want to clarify that ;)

Comment: Well, usually I DO get an inner and an outer ring. I will record a video tomorrow that demonstrates this.

Comment: that's super weird, it should only happen when there is an unbroken polygon to be drawn.

Comment: I have uploaded a video here: http://youtu.be/26NUVmq02A4 Sorry, it is super crappy, I have not used Blender for long. But you can see that the first loop is indeed on the inside and on the outside. The second one is not.

Comment: @MaikenRosk Your first loop goes up over the top and down the inside, then back out - it doesn't exist as two separate squares, just an outlined U-shape (single unbroken polygon)

Comment: I agree, if you view it from the side you can see it's an unbroken loop, while looping on the outside of the box and the inside is two separate loopdidoos.

Comment: But you see what I want to do, right? What would we be a proper way to do that? I think what I want to do is subdiving at a certain position.

Comment: My answer is a way to do that. please read it.

Answer (score 3):

By hovering over the inner edges, you should be able to do this. Make sure you are not near enough to the top of the mesh to cause issues of course.

[image: Example GIF]

If this did not work, try looking for missing faces, non-uniform geometry, duplicate vertices, or N-Gons (5+ vertex faces).